# Find average of numbers (with while loops; java)

Tags: java, while-loop, user-input

My code stops when the user inputs -1 (like it should) but the average printed is wrong.

This is what I have:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class averages_1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the scores:");
        double score = 0;
        double num = 0;
        double sum = 0;

    while (score != -1)
    {
        score = scan.nextDouble();
        sum += score;
        num++;
    }
    System.out.println("The average is:" + (sum/num));
}

}
```

If you enter 50 then 105 then -1, the output is

```
Enter the scores:

50

105

-1

The average is: 51.333333333333336
```

I just need to correct the average. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Or you could do `Stream.generate(scan::nextDouble).mapToDouble(d -> d).takeWhile(d -> d != -1).average()` (but it requires the latest version of Java).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You include the -1 in your average.

One way to avoid it is to add another condition :

```
while (score != -1)
{
    score = scan.nextDouble();
    if (score != -1) {
        sum += score;
        num++;
    }
}
```

However, a more elegant solution would read the first input before the loop, and only add valid inputs :

```
score = scan.nextDouble();
while (score != -1)
{
    sum += score;
    num++;
    score = scan.nextDouble();
}
```

In general, changing the variable used in the condition of the while loop should be the last thing you do in the iteration.

Comment: In this case, your num will have a number which is +1 of the num, so we need to again decrement the value, as in my answer. Then you will get the right average.

Comment: @Iqbal No, in both of my suggestions, `num` is incremented only when the input score is valid, so it has the correct value.

Comment: please check the 2nd example of you, you are incrementing the number before taking an input. num becomes 1, before taking 1st input. Num becomes 2, beofre 2nd input, and if the -1 is the third input, then the num is 3. But to take average of 2 numbers the num must have 2 as the value. thus you have to decrement the num, and then take the average. Please check my answer for the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Iqbal The input in the loop is already for the 2nd, 3rd ... number. Erans code is correct and is actually quite elegant (I would prefer the first proposal)

Comment: In this case, you are repeating the input Scan, do you think this is very good approach to repeat the code.

Comment: @Eran A do...while would do just fine here, In fact it's a story book example for using do...while loops

Comment: I agree, but thought to suggest :-)

Answer (score 5):

you can read input within the condition of your `while loop` instead,
this way as soon as you read `-1` you quit the loop and it won't be added to your `sum` variable

```
while ((score=scan.nextDouble()) != -1)
{
    sum += score;
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just add the last -1 to your sum and still count it as number. You have to `break;` your loop if your input was -1.

Comment: should I place the break; after num++; ?

Comment: Break won't work unless you have a conditional check in your code for `score != -1`. So use the code as in my answer, it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Melanie You have to check whether your input was a -1 and only then use the break. That would be an easy fix. More elegant however is the proposed answer of Eran. He/She only adds the numbers that are not -1 to your sum and only counts them as number too.

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing `num` even for `input==-1`, which is not a valid input, but a escape character...

Either modify the logic or just correct the snippet:

```
System.out.println("The average is:" + (++sum/--num));
```

Comment: He is also adding -1 to sum aswell. So your solution won't calculate right average...

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class averages_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the scores:");
        double score = 0;
        double num = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        while (score != -1) {
            sum += score;
            score = scan.nextDouble();
            num++;
        }
        num--;
        System.out.println("The average is:" + (sum/num));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so then just use this

```
while (score != -1) {
        if (scope != -1){
           sum += score;
           score = scan.nextDouble();
           num++;
        }
    }
```

It's not pretty, but like everyone else is telling you, don't add -1 to score since its your escape character.